# Rails AJAX form submits as JSON instead of JS

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jquery

The following form:

```
<%= form_for @bid, remote:true do |f| %>

    <%= f.label :amount, 'What's your bid??' %>
    <%= f.text_field :amount %>


    <br>
    <%= f.submit "Bid", class: "btn" %>
<% end %>
```

allows users to submit a bid ebay style by clicking the "Bid" button. Upon doing so I would like an AJAX request to update my html to display a confirmation message like so:

```
//create.js.erb
$(".modal-top-messages").html("<%= escape_javascript(render('layouts/messages')) %>")
```

Controller code looks something like this:

```
def create
    @bid = current_user.bids.build(params[:bid])

    if @bid.save
      flash.now[:success] = "Bid submitted"
    else
      error_msg = "Error submitting bid. Please try again.\n"  + @bid.errors.collect { |k, v| "#{k}: #{v}" }.join
    end

    if error_msg
      flash.now[:error] = error_msg
    end

    respond_to do |format|
      format.js
      format.html { redirect_to company_path }

    end
  end
```

Now when I hit the "Bid" button in my view I see an error in my console:

```
Started POST "/bids.json" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-07-11 18:48:59 -0700
Processing by BidsController#create as JSON
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"?", "authenticity_token"=>"F5aQUGgXMYeTZQEpkAs6a501lsrgx
SIr+JxHS8O2Qrw=", "bid"=>{"amount"=>""}}
  ?[1m?[36mUser Load (0.0ms)?[0m  ?[1mSELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users
"."id" = 3 LIMIT 1?[0m
  ?[1m?[35m (0.0ms)?[0m  begin transaction
  ?[1m?[36m (0.0ms)?[0m  ?[1mrollback transaction?[0m
Completed 406 Not Acceptable in 15ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
```

I believe the 406 is due to the lack of "respond_to format.json" in my controller. What I can't figure out is why a JSON response is sent in the first place.

Comment: have you tried removing the `{}` ?

Comment: yeah, that didn't do anything

Comment: It looks like the bid is failing to save.

Comment: Well, that may be but I think the 406 specifically indicates that the controller cannot supply the format requested

Comment: By default Rails sends remote forms as json, you can change it with `data-type` https://github.com/rails/jquery-ujs/wiki/Unobtrusive-scripting-support-for-jQuery#data-type-set-ajax-request-type-for-data-remote-requests